# Eloquent relationship of a grouping of a relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to create a relationship for a model for an Order which will group items by their menu item, to end up with the following data structure (when outputted to JSON):

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "items": [
    {
      "menu_item_id": 32,
      "items": [
        {
          "id": 456,
          "order_id": 123,
          "menu_item_id": 32
        },
        {
          "id": 457,
          "order_id": 123,
          "menu_item_id": 32
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "menu_item_id": 37,
      "items": [
        {
          "id": 466,
          "order_id": 123,
          "menu_item_id": 37
        },
        {
          "id": 467,
          "order_id": 123,
          "menu_item_id": 37
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have the following models & relationships:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    ...
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\OrderItem');
    }
    ...
}

class OrderItem extends Model
{
    ...
    public function menuItem()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\MenuItem');
    }
    ...
}
```

Any suggestions on how?

EDIT:
I'm currently getting:

```
{
    "id": 388,
    "items": [{
        "id": 891,
        "order_id": 388,
        "menu_item_id": 928,
        "menu_item": {
            "id": 928,
            "price_in_cents": 2795,
        }
    }, {
        "id": 892,
        "order_id": 388,
        "menu_item_id": 929,
        "menu_item": {
            "id": 929,
            "price_in_cents": 2495,
            "name": "Teriyaki Salmon",
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Title needs to be fixed

Comment: What do u get now

Comment: I edited my question with the current data I'm getting for App\Models\Order::with(['items.menuItem'])->first()